# 1 Line on controller to auto input datetime.now in new records

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Some 3 days ago a friend helped me with this, but I needed to rebuild my controller and view and lost the command that auto input "datetime.now" when client create something new on web compiled
I remember that was a line on:

[image: inside if]

I'm from Brazil, sorry about some language errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please do not post code as an image. Your question itself, should include all relevant code in text.

That said, there's nothing really special here. If you want to set a property to `DateTime.Now` before saving in your controller, you just do *that*:

```
foo.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
db.Foos.Add(foo);
db.SaveChanges();
```

However, it's better if you're going to do this with any frequency, to actually use a custom getter and setter on your property to handle this automatically:

```
private DateTime? createdDate;
public DateTime CreatedDate
{
    get { return createdDate ?? DateTime.Now; }
    set { createdDate = value; }
}
```

That way, if the property hasn't been explicitly set, it will automatically return `DateTime.Now`. After it has been set, it will return whatever it was set to.

Finally, you should avoid `DateTime.Now`. The value of that is the local *server* time, and really has no relevance to anything. If you ever co-locate your site on servers in different timezones, the value in the database quickly becomes meaningless. You should always use `DateTime.UtcNow`, which returns the current date and time in UTC, which will always be the same regardless of local server time. Or, if you insist on storing local time, then use `DateTimeOffset.Now`, so you'll at least have a timezone component to work with.